# How to use Tensorflow-gpu when both Tensorflow and Tensorflow-gpu are installed?

Tags: tensorflow

I have both TF and TF-GPU installed in the same virtual environment. when I test it in iPython terminal, it shows that TensorFlow, not TensorFlow-GPU is used. However, I want the GPU version to be used.

How to do that? Shouldn't I installed both in the same environment? Thanks.

Comment: In my environment python will pick up the last tensorflow version installed and stick to it

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Wish I knew a better answer